# ./etc/opt/OS is taking the 49GB of my space while it's not a dir

Tags: directory, disk-usage, disk, etc, opt

```
du -cha --max-depth=1 /etc/opt/OS | grep -E "M|G"

49G     /etc/opt/OS
49G     total



root:/etc/opt# cd /etc/opt/OS
bash: cd: /etc/opt/OS: Not a directory
root:/etc/opt# dir
OS
```

what is the OS thing in ./etc/opt and is it safe to just delete it?

Comment: There are only two packages with a file in /etc/opt, both chrome extensions. That file is probably from some third party package -- maybe a virtual machine.  What does file /etc/opt/OS output (add answer to original posting).

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; and your final question refers to a *relative* directory that differs to the *static* directory you mention your pastes (ie. the `.` makes it relative to $PWD thus it may differ or be the same).  Have you looked at what is is (ie. ask your system to identify it using `file` etc?)

Comment: FYI:  My Ubuntu system has no such file named `/etc/opt/OS` but given I don't know $PWD for you, I can't give anything with regards `./etc/opt/OS` let alone your OS, product & release details are unknown thus may differ to my own. We're limited to details you provide us.